# How Can I set environment variables on AWS EC2?

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a Django application to be hosted on AWS EC2. Some of my variables are sensitive and have to be excluded from version control. Some are not sensitive but the values vary from environment to environment. To achieve this, I am saving the values in the environment and accessing via the code.
CircleCI provides a way of achieving this by **Environment Variables** of the project. Heroku also provides similar functionality.

Please how can I set these variables in AWS Ec2?

Comment: you should read about .env file. You can access the environment variables from that file using python. The flow is you created a mock .env.example file with the required variable keys(not values), push it to version control, when you have the code on the server from cloning the repo, clone a .env file from the env.example file and start editing it with the variable values on EC2 server

Comment: The analog to Heroku on AWS is Elastic Beanstalk, and Elastic Beanstalk allows you to set environment variables in a similar manner to Heroku. EC2 is a lower-level service that just provides you a virtual machine running your choice of operating system. You have to go into the operating system to setup things like environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file .env where setting.py file exists.After That set the enviroment variables
in that file

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
AWS_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID
```

and set other necessary variables related to the AWS

Comment: Thank you, @Tanveer Ahmad. This approach will mean committing the `.env` file to git and pushing it to Github. I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: The .env should be in .gitignore.  Commit a mock .env, send that to git, include instructions in your readme, and ask every dev/user to create his own locally w actual values.

Comment: yup @james.garris